# Why does this code not work? (Python and PyGame)

Tags: python, image, time, pygame, blit

```
import math, sys, os, pygame, random, time

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
pygame.display.set_caption('Tester.')
pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)


def smileMove():
    smiley = pygame.image.load('smiley.png')
    random.seed()
    xMove = random.randrange(1,501)
    yMove = random.randrange(1,501)

    screen.blit(smiley,(xMove,yMove))


c = 0

while c <5:
    smileMove()
    time.sleep(3)
    c = c + 1

pygame.quit()
```

I'm very new to programming and I'm just trying out a few basic things with PyGame.
The screen remains black and no smiley faces appear. I am trying to make the faces appear on the black background, and change to another random place every 3 seconds, 5 times and then quit.

Comment: You really ought to work through a tutorial. Almost any `pygame` program should have an event loop. And you should never call `sleep` in the middle of handling an event. (If you sleep for 3 seconds, your program won't respond to any external input, so your computer will probably put up a beachball of death, or the equivalent for your platform.)

Comment: I will at some point, however I just wanted to try and get something basic down. Thanks for the tip though. Is there any way I can get it to pause without calling sleep?

Comment: You want to set up a "timer handler", or set up an "idle handler" that checks the time every iteration until it's 3 seconds after you started. This is very hard to explain in a 600-character comment, but a tutorial will give you plenty of examples. And really, the best way to "try to get something basic down" is to work through the first steps of a tutorial, not to write random code and cross your fingers.

Comment: at least call pump, so the system will know the program is working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a call to `pygame.display.flip()` to actually update the window contents- put it just before your `time.sleep` call.

My advice at this early stage of experimenting with Python and the pygame API would be to try stuff at the interactive console..

Comment: To add more clarification to this, so you know why you actually need to call flip(), pygame uses what's called double-buffering.  That means that the image currently on the screen and the image you are rendering to are separate.  This allows you to draw only complete images to the screen, which eliminates some tearing and artifacts you would otherwise see (essentially an incomplete image being drawn over a complete one).  All of your screen.blit() calls are drawing to a hidden buffered image.  When you call flip, you are "flipping" the drawn image for the buffered one.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, it needs to be in a while loop (at least if you are going to do much more) also, you are missing the background. this should work:

```
import math, sys, os, pygame, random, time

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
pygame.display.set_caption('Tester.')
pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)
white = ( 255, 255, 255)

def smileMove():
    screen.fill(white)
    smiley = pygame.image.load('smiley.png')
    random.seed()
    xMove = random.randrange(1,501)
    yMove = random.randrange(1,501)

    screen.blit(smiley,(xMove,yMove))

c = 0
done = False
while done==False:
    for event in pygame.event.get(): # User did something
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # If user clicked close
            done=True # Flag that we are done so we exit this loop

    screen.fill(white)
    while c <5:
        smileMove()
        pygame.display.flip()
        c = c + 1
        time.sleep(3)
pygame.quit()
```